# Override Default TabIndex Behaviour to select checked element first

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, accessibility, tabindex

I have two radio buttons with labels Yes & No both with their label tabIndex set to 0. No is set checked by default. Also they are custom radio buttons.

[image]

What I want to achieve is -

1. When a user hits the Tab key, the checked radio button should be focused. (By default, the first element is focused.)
2. When the user hits the tab again, it should go about its natural behavior and focus on the next element.

Here's a pseudo-code of what I have tried:

```
isTab = false
isChecked = false

switch(event.keyCode):
   case 9:
     if (!isTab):
       isTab = true;
       event.preventDefault();
       for (let radio of radioButtons):
         if radio.isChecked:
            radio.focus()
            isChecked = true;
     
       if (!isChecked):
          // if none are selected, focus on first
          radioButtons[0].focus()
```

This is working for only 1st time when the default case, No is selected. But when I select Yes and press tab, the focus remains on the Yes, and does not move to the next element.

I want to keep the focus on the selected radio first, then on the subsequent tab press I want to move focus as normal.

Help highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have a tabindex set? Radio buttons do exactly what you ask by default so are you creating a custom control? Maybe add the html as well?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Edited my question. The tabindex is on labels, so it can have a full focus around the label as well, also they're custom radio buttons extended from the default ones.

Comment: One of the biggest problems you are going to face with this is that other keys other than the tab key are used by screen reader users to navigate. Have you considered using CSS to do the heavy lifting? https://jsfiddle.net/np1kc4v3/ is a quick example of how to achieve this.

Comment: and here is one with a different design and an item already checked https://jsfiddle.net/np1kc4v3/1/, native elements make life 100 times easier. Is there something in particular that means you can't use native elements?